# Load content from URL into content-column

Tags: html

I am facing an issue with my script that uses the jQuery .load() method. The script is designed to load the content from a URL into a specific element on my page when a user clicks on a nav link. However, I am receiving the error message "TypeError: $(...).load is not a function." and I am not sure why this is happening.

Here is my script:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Add click event listener to all nav links
    $(document).on('click', '.nav-link', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // Get the URL of the clicked link
      var url = $(this).attr('href');
  
      // Load the content from the URL into the content-column
      $('#content-column').load(url);
    });
  });
</script>
```

I have made sure that I am using the latest version of jQuery and that it is properly included in my HTML file.

If anyone has any experience with this issue or knows how to resolve it, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Currently all scripts I have tried either result in a redirect to the actual url or the script works for one click and then stops working after that.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a simplified version of your HTML page, or at least the relevant markup. Your error seems to indicate that there isn't an element with `id="content-column"` anywhere in the page

Comment: Hi Tieson, thanks for your response - the url is ocventures.xyz 

I have id="content-column" underneath the nav-link section is displayed like this:

    <div class="col-sm-9 p-0">
      <main id="content-column">
        <h1>Welcome to OC Ventures</h1>
        
      </main>
    </div>

Comment: You can use the "Edit" action, in the lower left part of your question, to add more details (and, honestly, probably remove most of your failed attempted - not sure how relevant they are). That being said, if `$('#content-column').load(url);` is returning a "normal" web page, you're probably injecting a full HTML page into your current page, which is both invalid and will create errors like you're seeing.

Comment: Interesting - do you know of any resources that I could read up on this a bit at all?

That is basically what I am doing - it works fine for the first click of a nav-link but from there it looks like the event listeners are removed. I just don't fully understand why it would be invalid, is it more of a policy thing? If you know of any sites that I could checkout to see how it is done better that would be mint - I have basically just tried to build this from looking at Semrush lol.

Comment: The `load()` function you're using is mostly just a convenience wrapper around `$.get`. You're making an HTTP request to some endpoint on your site, and then `load()` inserts the response into the element on which it's called. This is covered in the docs - http://api.jquery.com/load/ - as well as some options for filtering the result

Comment: As for why injecting a full HTML into another HTML page is invalid... that's a rather comprehensive topic to cover, but the gist is that the HTML spec says it's invalid, and browsers vendors for the most part adhere to the spec.

Comment: Awesome mate, thanks for that, I am having a bit of trouble with $.get functions across the site in general so I'll do a bit of reading. I appreciate your help